# Create works but get_or_create doesn't . Django 1.8 + Python 3.4

Tags: python, django

This code works perfectly:

```
for i in m:
        print(i)
        event = Event.objects.create(title=titles[i])
        # event = Event()
        event.title = titles[i]
        event.image_link = images[i]
        event.city = cities[i]
        # event.place = placies[i]
        # event.date = dates[i]
        event.save()
        print (Event.objects.all())
```

But if I change create to get_or_create , it doesn't work at all without any errors or something. Possibly there is something missing in my understanding how get_or_create works?

```
for i in m:
        print(i)
        event = Event.objects.get_or_create(title=titles[i])
        # event = Event()
        event.title = titles[i]
        event.image_link = images[i]
        event.city = cities[i]
        # event.place = placies[i]
        # event.date = dates[i]
        event.save()
        print (Event.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_or_create` [returns a *tuple*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create); the first element is the instance, the second is a boolean of whether the instance was created.

You should do:

```
event, created = Event.objects.get_or_create(title=titles[i])
```

Comment: didn't help . Wouldn't it  work otherwise without a boolean?

Comment: Didn't help *how*? What happened? What message do you see? And what do you mean by your second sentence?

Comment: for checking purpose I print i to the console. The only output is 0, and new object is not created . By second sentence I ask, whether its absolutely wrong not having created boolean

Comment: daniel give you the solution at your problem. get_or_create() returns a list of two element. First one, object, and second a boolean to tell you if this object was created or not. If you don't want the boolean result, juste write : event = Event.objects.get_or_create(title=titles[i])[0]